# Model independent (or reasonable assumption) bounds on OTM put price given an ATM call price

Tags: options, derivatives, arbitrage, put-call-parity

I am looking for model independent (or weak/reasonable assumption) bounds on price of a OTM vanilla put on strike $k1$, conditional on an observable price for a ATM call at some strike $k2$. I understand I can use call put parity and the fact that calls are decreasing in strike, however I am looking for something stronger than that (with not too ridiculous assumptions of course). Any help is appreciated.

The context is that of a vanilla market which only has liquid observable prices of ATM calls but not much else.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, but I doubt whether anything more can be said other than that Lee's no arbitrage bounds have to be satisfied if you are looking for strictly model independent and arbitrage free conditions.

Comment: @FridoRolloos I am quite open to model assumptions; just depends on what assumptions they are.

Comment: I second @FridoRolloos: I think we cannot extract *meaningful* information out of one point and a couple of no-arb conditions for a different point in the contract space, alone. You *could* try to extrapolate the IV or price surface of your liquid options and approximate the OTM vol/price, of course; maybe add a couple of more extreme scenarios to the mix to stress your result. Bar that, you can only get the no-arb *box* where the price could be (i.e. the bracket of inner value and the put price at $k_2$), I think.